# What is the difference between $A\subset\Bbb{R^m}$ and $(X,m)$ being totally bounded

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Sorry for the loosely expressed question.

Here is my actual problem. I want to show that if $A\subset\Bbb{R^m}$ is totally bounded wrt. $d$, then $A$ is bounded wrt. $d$, where $d$ is the Euclidean metric.

Also, given that $(X,m)$ is a metric space and $A\subset X$, if $A$ is totally bounded wrt. $m$, then $A$ is bounded wrt. $m$.

For the second one I have considered the following;

By the definition of totally boundedness, we know that there are finitely many points and $\epsilon-balls$ defined arround them covering $A$ for any $\epsilon$. Thus, we can pick two arbitrary points, say $x_i$ and $x_j$, among those finitely many points and consider the distance between two arbitrary elements , say $b$ and $a$, both of them being in the $\epsilon-balls$ defined arround $x_i$ and $x_j$, respectively. Thus, the distance $b$ and $a$ will be bounded by $d(x_i,x_j)+2\epsilon$ and since we have finitely many $x$ we are done.

What I want to know is whether the above-mentioned reasoning is correct and if and how it can be applied to the first question.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** If we are given $\varepsilon$ and $N_{\varepsilon}$ so that $N_{\varepsilon}$ balls of radius $\varepsilon$ cover $A$, then the diameter of the set cannot be larger than $N_\varepsilon\cdot \varepsilon=:R$. So, fix $x\in A$. Show that $A\subset B_{R}(x)\subset X.$